# Conditional Statement for arima.sim() Function: Error in Task 1 Failed - "Inconsistent Specification of 'ma' Order

Tags: r, if-statement, arima, random-seed

I am trying to write a function with `arima.sim()` function in `R` such that I only need to input the variables of any of the `ARMA` families to get the `seeds` that will produce my type of `ARMA` simulation.

Two out of my three (2/3) cases are true when I use the following

```
arma_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, ma11, ar22, ma22, ar33, ma33, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, k1, j2, k2, j3, k3, arr1, maa1, arr2, maa2, arr3, maa3){

  output <- if (p == 1) {

    ar1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, arr1){
      future::plan(future::multisession)
      n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
      cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)
      doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
  
      message('processing...')
      `%dopar%` <- foreach::`%dopar%`
      i <- a:z
      res <- foreach::foreach(i = a:z, .packages = c('foreach', 'forecast')) %dopar% {
        set.seed(i)
        mod <- stats::arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = c(ar11), order = c(p, d, q)), sd = sd)
        best.mod <- forecast::auto.arima(mod, ic = "aicc")
        (cf <- best.mod$coef)
        if (length(cf) == 0) {
          rep(NA, 2)
        } else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
                   substr(cf["ar1"], 1, j1) %in% arr1) {
          c(cf, seed = I)
        } else {
          rep(NA, 2)
        }
      }
      message(' done!\n')
  
      res1 = res[!sapply(res, anyNA)]
  
      parallel::stopCluster(cl)
      options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
  
      res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))
  
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
  
      res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
    }

    ar1_sim_search(a = a,  z = z, n = n, p = 1, d = d, q = q, ar11 = ar11, sd = sd, j1 = j1, arr1 = arr1)




 #######################################################################

  } else if (p == 1 && q == 1) {

    arma1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, ma11, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, k1, arr1, maa1){
      future::plan(future::multisession)
      n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
      cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)
      doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
  
      message('processing...')
      `%dopar%` <- foreach::`%dopar%`
      i <- a:z
      res <- foreach::foreach(i = a:z, .packages = c('foreach', 'forecast')) %dopar% {
        set.seed(i)
        mod <- stats::arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = ar11, ma = ma11, order = c(p, d, q)), sd = sd)
        best.mod <- forecast::auto.arima(mod, ic = "aicc")
        (cf <- best.mod$coef)
        if (length(cf) == 0) {
          rep(NA, 2)
        }  else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|ma1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
                    substr(cf["ar1"], 1, j1) %in% arr1 & substr(cf["ma1"], 1, k1) %in% maa1) {
          c(cf, seed = I)
        } else {
          rep(NA, 2)
        }
      }
      message(' done!\n')
  
      res1 = res[!sapply(res, anyNA)]
  
      parallel::stopCluster(cl)
      options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
  
      res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))
  
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
  
      res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
    }

    arma1_sim_search(a = a,  z = z, n = n, p = 1, d = d, q = 1, ar11 = ar11, ma11 = ma11, sd = sd, j1 = j1, k1 = k1, arr1 = arr1, maa1 = maa1)
  ##############################################################

  } else {

    ma1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ma11, p, d, q, sd = 1, k1, maa1){
      future::plan(future::multisession)
      n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
      cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)
      doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
  
      message('processing...')
      `%dopar%` <- foreach::`%dopar%`
      i <- a:z
      res <- foreach::foreach(i = a:z, .packages = c('foreach', 'forecast')) %dopar% {
        set.seed(i)
        mod <- stats::arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ma = c(ma11), order = c(p, d, q)), sd = sd)
        best.mod <- forecast::auto.arima(mod, ic = "aicc")
        (cf <- best.mod$coef)
        if (length(cf) == 0) {
          rep(NA, 2)
        } else if (all(grepl(c("ma1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
                   substr(cf["ma1"], 1, k1) %in% maa1) {
          c(cf, seed = I)
        } else {
          rep(NA, 2)
        }
      }
      message(' done!\n')
  
      res1 = res[!sapply(res, anyNA)]
  
      parallel::stopCluster(cl)
      options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
  
      res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))
  
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
  
      res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
  }

    ma1_sim_search(a = a,  z = z, n = n, p = p, d = d, q = 1, ma11 = ma11, sd = sd, k1 = k1, maa1 = maa1)
  }
  ##############################################################################

  return(output)
}
```

The first case works well with this output.

```
arma_sim_search(a = 1,  z = 1000, n = 25, p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, ar11 = 0.8, sd = 1, j1 = 3, arr1 = "0.8")
#processing...
 #done!

#         ar1 seed
#64 0.8835177   16
#2  0.8026257   30
#9  0.8115264   42
#19 0.8246183   43
#67 0.8971222   49
```

The `second` case is giving me error.

```
arma_sim_search(a = 1,  z = 1000, n = 25, p = 1, d = 0, q = 1, ar11 = 0.4, ma11 = 0.5, sd = 1, j1 = 3, k1 = 3, arr1 = "0.4", maa1 = "0.5")
```

I got this `error` message: `Error in { : task 1 failed - "inconsistent specification of 'ma' order"`  
The third case works well like the first.

```
arma_sim_search(a = 1,  z = 1000, n = 25, p = 0, d = 0, q = 1, ma11 = 0.8, sd = 1, k1 = 3, maa1 = "0.8")
#processing...
 #done!

#          ma1 seed  intercept
#81  0.8551335   24         NA
#14  0.8090642   28         NA
#12  0.8080051   29         NA
#43  0.8314141   33         NA
```

This is the skeletal image of my function: the first case is when the expression is an `AR1` with `p == 1` the second is when the expression is an `ARMA11` with `p ==1 && q ==1` and the last is a case when the expression is an `MA1` case when `q == 1`.

```
arma_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, ma11, ar22, ma22, ar33, ma33, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, k1, j2, k2, j3, k3, arr1, maa1, arr2, maa2, arr3, maa3){

  output <- if (p == 1) {

    ar1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, arr1){
      AR1 EXPRESION

   }
    ar1_sim_search(a = a,  z = z, n = n, p = 1, d = d, q = q, ar11 = ar11, sd = sd, j1 = j1, arr1 = arr1)
    ########################################################

  } else if (p == 1 && q == 1) {

    arma1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, ma11, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, k1, arr1, maa1){
      ARMA11 EXPRESION
    }

    arma1_sim_search(a = a,  z = z, n = n, p = 1, d = d, q = 1, ar11 = ar11, ma11 = ma11, sd = sd, j1 = j1, k1 = k1, arr1 = arr1, maa1 = maa1)
  ##################################################

  } else {

    ma1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ma11, p, d, q, sd = 1, k1, maa1){
      MA1 EXPRESION
  }

    ma1_sim_search(a = a,  z = z, n = n, p = p, d = d, q = 1, ma11 = ma11, sd = sd, k1 = k1, maa1 = maa1)
  }
  ##############################################################################

  return(output)
}
arma_sim_search(a = 1,  z = 1000, n = 25, p = 1, d = 0, q = 1, ar11 = 0.4, ma11 = 0.5, sd = 1, j1 = 3, k1 = 3, arr1 = "0.4", maa1 = "0.5")
```

Meanwhile, when I ran the function of `case two` alone it ran well.

```
    arma1_sim_search <- function(a, z, n, ar11, ma11, p, d, q, sd = 1, j1, k1, arr1, maa1){
      future::plan(future::multisession)
      n_cores <- parallel::detectCores()
      cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n_cores)
      doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = n_cores)
  
      message('processing...')
      `%dopar%` <- foreach::`%dopar%`
      i <- a:z
      res <- foreach::foreach(i = a:z, .packages = c('foreach', 'forecast')) %dopar% {
        set.seed(i)
        mod <- stats::arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ar = ar11, ma = ma11, order = c(p, d, q)), sd = sd)
        best.mod <- forecast::auto.arima(mod, ic = "aicc")
        (cf <- best.mod$coef)
        if (length(cf) == 0) {
          rep(NA, 2)
        }  else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|ma1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
                    substr(cf["ar1"], 1, j1) %in% arr1 & substr(cf["ma1"], 1, k1) %in% maa1) {
          c(cf, seed = I)
        } else {
          rep(NA, 2)
        }
      }
      message(' done!\n')
  
      res1 = res[!sapply(res, anyNA)]
  
      parallel::stopCluster(cl)
      options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
  
      res2 <- tibble::tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))
  
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
  
      res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
      res2[order(res2$seed), ]
    }

    arma1_sim_search(a = 1,  z = 1000, n = 50, p = 1, d = 0, q = 1, ar11 = 0.2, ma11 = 0.7, sd = 1, j1 = 3, k1 = 3, arr1 = 0.2, maa1 = 0.7)
#processing...
# done!

#        ar1       ma1 seed
#5 0.2887975 0.7388537  212
#4 0.2871108 0.7819748  229
#3 0.2858437 0.7425638  249
#2 0.2728310 0.7659739  310
#1 0.2574142 0.7674407  935
```

Comment: I have tried to make this question simple,  but I also need to put every premise present.

Comment: the `if` statement starts with `if (p == 1)` and then you write `else if (p == 1 && q == 1)` which seems to be the code you'd like to use in the second test case. However, you'll never go to this code because `p == 1` is true if `p == 1 && q == 1`, so that the first part of the if runs. You could try putting first `p == 1 && q == 1` if condition and then `p == 1` for the else if

Comment: `Error in order(list(ar1 = 0.817178024963955, ar1 = 0.800814565645978), : 
unimplemented type 'list' in 'listgreater'` That is the error message I now get when I execute your suggestion. `arma_sim_search(a = 1,  z = 1000, n = 200, p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, ar11 = 0.8, sd = 1, j1 = 3, arr1 = "0.8")`

Comment: I also get this error without implementing my suggestion, that's why I didn't try to go further as I wasn't able to run your code even to for test case 1 : are you sure your example is [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DanielJames My suggestion would be to look closely at `output <- if (p == 1) {`, my intuition is you want to change this. Why? You create a return structure based on an if / else structure. So I see two scenarios based on your description that scenario 2 works standalone. a) You have a global variable that is somehow getting overwritten elsewhere or your if-else structure is creating an interpreter problem.  Either, way I'd suggest simplification.

Comment: @DanielJames My approach would be to pull out each function and have each separately return `output` that would be cleaner, separately I'd put a prefix on all the internal function variables to debug f1_*, f2_*, f3_* so we could distinguish and identify any globals being used across the three functions. Anyway, I hope this points you towards a solution. Good karma flying your way.

Comment: I'm not sure you need all that parallel/future stuff for the sake of reproducible example, unless you suspect it could be part of the cause for your bug.